# Installing gcc4.9 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, g++4.9

I tried the following but I get the errors at the end. In order to make sure that 4.8.2 was not interfering, I removed it.

Any suggestions would be great!

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++-4.9

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 g++-4.9 : Depends: gcc-4.9-base (= 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04) but 4.9.2-10 is to be installed
           Depends: gcc-4.9 (= 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libstdc++-4.9-dev (= 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
idf@C55t-A:/etc/apt$
```

Comment: Shouldn't be asked  here. ask it on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com)

Comment: Thanks. Moved it there.